# comma separated Javascript code assignment methods

Tags: javascript

I am unable to understand this type of javascript assignment where values are provided comma separated. How it works and what's the purpose of this?

```
var self = this, selectedTabPane, resultsGridQuery,
                headers = self.app.SessionInfo && self.app.SessionInfo.headers,
                hierarchyId = self.params.hierarchyId,
                gridColumns;
```

In above code self is current module.I am completely confused what will be assigned to self this or selectedTabPane etc anyone can help with that?

Comment: @Satpal—all the variables are declared before any assignments take place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should simply reformat the code and it will be more clear :

```
var self = this,
    selectedTabPane,
    resultsGridQuery,
    headers = self.app.galSysSessionInfo && self.app.galSysSessionInfo.headers,
    hierarchyId = self.params.hierarchyId,
    gridColumns;
```

this is equivalent to :

```
var self,
    selectedTabPane,
    resultsGridQuery,
    headers,
    hierarchyId,
    gridColumns;

self = this;
headers = self.app.galSysSessionInfo && self.app.galSysSessionInfo.headers;
hierarchyId = self.params.hierarchyId;
```

There is 6 declared variables and 3 assigned with the values indicated above...

Comment: can you please also describe this line "headers = self.app.galSysSessionInfo && self.app.galSysSessionInfo.headers;"

Comment: This simply checks if the 2 variables `self.app.galSysSessionInfo` and `self.app.galSysSessionInfo.headers` exists or not.

Comment: and last one will be assigned to header?

Comment: Yes, exactly, see MDN : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators

Comment: +1 for pointing out that the declarations are processed first, then the assignments later when execution begins.

Comment: @MShahzad—or the first if it's falsey (e.g. 0, null, NaN, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Your code is the same as:

```
var self = this; 
var selectedTabPane;
var resultsGridQuery;
var headers = self.app.galSysSessionInfo && self.app.galSysSessionInfo.headers;
var hierarchyId = self.params.hierarchyId;
var gridColumns;
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript allows comma separated variable declaration. You can declare the variables separated by commas. 
For example var i; var j; can be written as var i,j;
Here self will be assigned with the value of this( the current Object).
You haven't assigned any value to selectedTabPane so it won't have any value.
Also we can declare as well as initialize variables as shown below.

```
var i=0,k=i,j;
```

**Edit:**
variable headers will have boolean value. This will be true if `self.app.galSysSessionInfo` and `self.app.galSysSessionInfo.headers` have any value otherwise false.

Comment: "*variable headers will have boolean value*" only if the first expression evaluates to false or if the first is truthy and the second to either true or false.